# kotlin Native Unknown Host Target

Tags: ios, kotlin, clion, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

I have created a new Hello World Kotlin Native project in CLion IDE but i am getting. kotlin native unknown host target error in.

```
 if (NOT KONANC_TARGET)
    if (APPLE)
        set(KONANC_TARGET macbook)
    elseif (UNIX)
        set(KONANC_TARGET linux)
    else ()
        **message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported host target")**
```

Because I am using windows and KONANC is only supported on macOS and Linux.
How can I fix this error and run Kotlin Native project on windows ?

I followed this [Kotlin Native Tutorial](http://developine.com/kotlin-native-ios-development-multiplatform-project/).

Answer (score 0):

This problem is known, but only limited to CMake files. You could still use Gradle or command line tools on Windows.